# How to Group by the Column using CAML Query

Tags: caml-query, jsom, caml

My requirement is to get the unique values from the column "Month" I am using the below code to group the column "Month" , But I don't find any luck .Can any one tell me what's wrong in my below code with JSOM.

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><GroupBy collapse='true'><FieldRef Name='Month' /></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Month' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Afaik you can't use group by like that, you'll have to use the `renderListData` function, and you need an [aggration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms468626.aspx) type.

Example:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", () => { 
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var viewXml = "<View><Aggregations Value='On'><FieldRef Name='Month' Type='COUNT'/></Aggregations><Query><GroupBy Collapse='TRUE' GroupLimit='100'><FieldRef Name='Month' /></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Month' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";
    var result = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListTitleHere').renderListData(viewXml);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(() => {
        console.log("res", JSON.parse( result.get_value()) ); 
    },(s,a) => {
        console.log("err",a.get_message());
    });
});
```

Edit:

To get from a specific folder you can add a `<Where />` to the `<Query />`

Example viewXml:

```
var viewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Aggregations Value='On'><FieldRef Name='Month' Type='COUNT'/></Aggregations><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Text'>"+_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+"/Shared Documents/FolderA</Value></Eq></Where><GroupBy Collapse='TRUE' GroupLimit='100'><FieldRef Name='Month' /></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Month' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";
```

Comment: can you tell me how to run that against a folder in the list?

Comment: @RichardHousham updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for that however that's digging through all the folders/files on the site. And we have a big site. So I'm concerned with performance. Any other ideas?. I've been playing around with this stuff for a few days and when I do it I get duplicates. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240764/csom-hightrust-sp2013-group-by-aggregate-giving-duplicates
Can you assist? I'm thinking it might be a 2013 issue and could be resolved in 2016 which we are set to move to. Should I just hold out?

Comment: Well I gave your idea a go but no dice. Still getting duplicates. FYI the RecursiveAll gives you back folders as well. No matter what the filter on the folder says. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333328/caml-queries-how-to-filter-folders-from-result-set

Comment: @RichardHousham yes ofc, you'll have to add FSObjType eq 0 to your where query to exlude folders if you don't want them

Comment: Thanks for the tip - gave it a go - no dice. Hoping for a solution is SP2016! When the upgrade comes. Still - thanks for your help and advice.